# Scraping a nested and unstructured table in python (lxml)

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml, lxml.html

The website I'm **scraping** (using **lxml** ) is working just fine with everything except a table, in which all the `tr`'s , `td`'s and heading `th`'s are nested & mixed and forms a unstructured HTML table.

```
<table class='table'>
    <tr>
        <th>Serial No.
            <th>Full Name
                <tr>
                    <td>1
                        <td rowspan='1'> John 
                            <tr>
                                <td>2
                                    <td rowspan='1'>Jane Alleman
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>3
                                                <td rowspan='1'>Mukul Jha
                                                 .....
                                                 .....
                                                 .....
</table>
```

I tried the following **xpaths**  but each of these is just giving me back a **empty list**.

```
persons = [x for x in tree.xpath('//table[@class="table"]/tr/th/th/tr/td/td/text()')]

persons = [x for x in tree.xpath('//table[@class="table"]/tr/td/td/text()')]

persons = [x for x in tree.xpath('//table[@class="table"]/tr/th/th/tr/td/td/text()') if x.isdigit() ==False] # to remove the serial no.s
```

Finally, what is the reason of such nesting, is it to prevent the **scraping** ?

Comment: show URL for this page and then we can test code.

Comment: maybe it is only mistake - someone forgot closing tags in code.

Comment: @furas its just a simple conversion of the actual table given by `page.text` of the site , given the structure is exact same . And second whats the need of such design. I think it is done to prevent scrapping (maybe).

Comment: See the last and second last table design in https://delhimetrorail.info/dwarka-sector-8-delhi-metro-station-to-dwarka-sector-14-delhi-metro-station

Comment: The last table your linked page seems pretty simple; can you post one full table from your site?

Comment: Its right in the OP

Comment: @JackFleeting Do you have any idea how to parse it?

Comment: Yes, for example, you could use pandas to read that table, if pandas is available to you.

Comment: Can you please help me exactly how? Because the table is still broken (nested) badly.

Comment: you can't do it only using `xpath`. You will have to create own parser - or rather create individual method for every row.

Comment: Why `xpath` is not enough ? Is it because of complicated nesting of table? @furas JackFleeting

Comment: because table is not correctly constructed. Some elements have opening `<td>` without closing `</td>`, some columns don't have even opening `<td>`, they use `<div></div>`. So there is one big mess in this table. There is no one rule which could describe how it is constructed. Every row has different mess.

Comment: for test I used BeautifulSoup and it shows HTML in original version with all mess but now I use `lxml` and `lxml.html.tostring(...)` to see table as HTML after loading it to memory and it seems it loads tags similar to browser and it creates correct table in memory so it needs normal xpath `/tr/td//text()` to get text from all cells.

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ (and __scraper__, __scrape__, __scraped__) not scrapping. ‘Scrapping’ means throwing away like rubbish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `lxml` loads table in similar way as browser and it creates correct structure in memory and you can see correct HTML when you use `lxml.html.tostring(table)`

So it has correctly formated table and it needs normal `'./tr/td//text()'` to get all values

```
import requests
import lxml.html

text = requests.get('https://delhimetrorail.info/dwarka-sector-8-delhi-metro-station-to-dwarka-sector-14-delhi-metro-station').text

s = lxml.html.fromstring(text)

table = s.xpath('//table')[1]

for row in table.xpath('./tr'):
    cells = row.xpath('./td//text()')
    print(cells)

print(lxml.html.tostring(table, pretty_print=True).decode())
```

Result

```
['Fare', ' DMRC Rs. 30']
['Time', '0:14']
['First', '6:03']
['Last', '22:24']
['Phone ', '8800793196']

<table class="table">
<tr>
<td title="Monday To Saturday">Fare</td>
<td><div> DMRC Rs. 30</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Time</td>
<td>0:14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>First</td>
<td>6:03</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last</td>
<td>22:24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Phone </td>
<td><a href="tel:8800793196">8800793196</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Oryginal HTML for comparition - there are missing closing tags

```
<table class='table'>
<tr><td  title='Monday To Saturday'>Fare<td><div> DMRC Rs. 30</div></tr>
<tr><td>Time<td>0:14</tr>
<tr><td>First<td>6:03</tr>
<tr><td>Last<td>22:24
<tr><td>Phone <td><a href='tel:8800793196'>8800793196</a></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: whats  s in `s.xpath` ?

Comment: I added `s = lxml.html.fromstring(text)`. Originally I had lines with `Beautifulsoup` in code which I cut off. It seems I removed too much lines :)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to furas' answer, but using pandas to scrape the last table on the page:

```
import requests
import lxml
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://delhimetrorail.info/dwarka-sector-8-delhi-metro-station-to-dwarka-sector-14-delhi-metro-station'
response = requests.get(url)

root = lxml.html.fromstring(response.text)
rows = []
info = root.xpath('//table[4]/tr/td[@rowspan]')
for i in info:
    row = []
    row.append(i.getprevious().text)
    row.append(i.text)
    rows.append(row)

columns = root.xpath('//table[4]//th/text()')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
df1
```

Output:

```
   Gate Dwarka Sector 14 Metro Station
0   1   Eros Etro Mall
1   2   Nirmal Bharatiya Public School
```